# Need to search using some character of the bar in google place api

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-places-api

I am using nearbysearch of google place api for listing all of the bar,restaurant in my webservice to provide list to mobile application.

I need to search like Pizz then all Pizza and other related restaurant and bar should come in list.

I am using below url for this but not getting any results.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=22.758,75.891&rankby=distance&types=bar|restaurant&keyword=bar|restaurant|wine&name=Pizza&key="My Api Key"
```

Anyone can help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to use something like a dictionary which have to predict for the user's choice (as far as i get your question). You can implement live ajax search in the input where the text is entered, searching through a previously inserted dictionary for instance in db or a plain text.